# Can we get the value of any getter method by extracting it using Methods[]?

Tags: java, methods

```
 Methods[] method =classname.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
```

In the above code, i want to get the value of particular method. Suppose above method will return some getter and setter methods. Can we get the value of any getter methods?

Comment: What language you are using?

Comment: You may [invoke](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Method.html#invoke(java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object...)) the method and get back the value.

Answer (score 1):

Like PeterMmm said, you can use invoke on Method, passing the object that you want the call to be made on, and any other arguments the method needs, as get methods usually don't have arguments, you can do like this:

```
import java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException;
import java.lang.reflect.Method;

public class MethodsTest {

    public int getA() {
        return 5;
    }

    public int getB() {
        return 8;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        MethodsTest obj = new MethodsTest();
        Method[] methods = obj.getClass().getDeclaredMethods();
        for (Method method: methods) {
            if (method.getName().startsWith("get"))
                try {
                    System.out.println(method.getName() + ": " + method.invoke(obj));
                } catch (IllegalAccessException | IllegalArgumentException | InvocationTargetException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
        }
    }
}
```

it will print:

```
getB: 8
getA: 5
```

hope it helps